# Is it possible to recover unpushed commits/file changes with only the .git folder?

Tags: git, flutter

I committed my code but before pushing it to Github, I used rm to delete all my local files except for everything in the .git folder. Is there any way to use just this .git folder to recover all my file changes or are they lost? I.e some way to reapply the changes committed locally to the outdated project from the remote. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah it I have all the history from the prev commits since they are on the remote but I can't seem to find a case where someone only has the .git folder to reapply all the changes from an unpushed commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the `git fsck` command will output the commits of dangling detached heads, then I just checked out the dangling commit and merged that back into the main without issues.